# Ionic 2 webview or native

Tags: react-native, ionic2

I didn't find information at ionicframework website.  For example, I saw many examples from react-native from react.parts website, and for example by using react-native I could render on google map custom objects, shapes, marker animation e.t.c, but on the other hand, Ionic2 renders google map as webview. So, is Ionic 2 will be native or webview based?

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure, if I understood your question but i will try to answer.

React Native and Ionic 2 is two really different thing. **React Native use native components and Ionic 2 use HTML components in WebView.** So if you want to use Google Maps in Ionic 2, you have to use Google Maps javascript SDK, but if you want to use it in React Native you will use Google Maps native mobile SDK wrapped in some React component.

But there is lot of Cordova plugins that can provide native functionality for your Ionic app. For example Google Maps plugin that will give you native mobile map SDK: https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Hope I helped you.